# Is there a SO Desktop notifier?

Tags: discussion, notifications

We all have a SE Android App, which is fantastic. **But, is there any way to get notified on my PC when I am not using the app?**.

Suppose, I am using a PC and I want to get notifications for my post as in some cases people want to instantly react to the post or the answer, which I guess is optimum and profitable for both the party.

Comment: Check out [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) for this kind of thing. Specifically: http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-large-scale, although it seems to be currently broken, but there are others.

Comment: [Stack Alert](http://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing) is probably what you want. Otherwise, find other apps from [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)

Comment: You could write your own, if you wanted.  SE wouldn't have to make it for you.

Comment: You might try looking at http://stackapps.com/. This might already exist.

Comment: "Stack Overflow wants to send notifications. Allow?" *~shudder~*

Answer (score 7):

The [Stack Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotifier-stackoverfl/dkicpibgdednbmlclkbcehckpfficabn?hl=en) proves to be a good solution for what you need. It is a Chrome extension which works. But I'm sure there are many.

It lets you select tags and give you desktop notifications when new questions are posted. Also you can link your global inbox and get notifications from there too.

Comment: link not working, 404 error

Answer (score 3):

Chrome extension that gives desktop notifications and has the same "tag" filter as on the regular site:

> ### [StackNotifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotifier/dkicpibgdednbmlclkbcehckpfficabn)
>
> Using stack notifier you can subscribe for set of tags in stackoverflow. It will show desktop notifications whenever new questions available for selected tags.
> When user click on the notification it will directly open the question in a new tab.

Comment: Anything for poor firefox users?

Comment: link not working, 404 error